Error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' after upgrade jint from 3.0.0-beta-2033 to 3.0.1
I run the script with Jint 3.0.0-beta-2033 and it works fine. Then, I upgrade Jint to 3.0.1, run the same script and get the error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'
The script is following:
(function () {
var callResult;
var flowHelper = require('flowHelper');
  var serverScriptExecutionContext = flowHelper.getServerScriptExecutionContext(context,request,args,readConfig,result,log,flowHelper);
var Fields = args.Fields;
var fieldsDataForSave = flowHelper.getValidatedPageDataForLoanCalculation(serverScriptExecutionContext);
      log.LogDebug('Calculate Loan Conditions Action fieldsDataForSave: ' + JSON.stringify(fieldsDataForSave));
callResult = JSON.parse(__remote_call__(context.nodes.loans, 'SaveFields', __jsonify__({"appId": context.AppId, "fields": fieldsDataForSave})));
}());

I had some null values inside the script, but substitution these values to something else didn't help. How can I find what is the root cause of the error and fix it?
Upgrade to the latest release version of Jint didn't help as well
full log of error is below:
Method CalculateLoanConditions has thrown an exception.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Expressions.JintExpression.GetValue(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.EsprimaExtensions.TryGetKey[T](T expression, Engine engine, Boolean resolveComputed)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Expressions.JintObjectExpression.BuildObjectNormal(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Expressions.JintExpression.GetValue(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Expressions.JintCallExpression.ArgumentListEvaluation(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Expressions.JintCallExpression.EvaluateInternal(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Expressions.JintExpression.GetValue(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Statements.JintReturnStatement.ExecuteInternal(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.Native.Function.ScriptFunction.Call(JsValue thisObject, JsValue[] arguments)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Expressions.JintCallExpression.EvaluateInternal(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Expressions.JintExpression.GetValue(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Statements.JintReturnStatement.ExecuteInternal(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.Native.Function.ScriptFunction.Call(JsValue thisObject, JsValue[] arguments)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Expressions.JintCallExpression.EvaluateInternal(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Expressions.JintExpression.GetValue(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Statements.JintVariableDeclaration.ExecuteInternal(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.Native.Function.ScriptFunction.Call(JsValue thisObject, JsValue[] arguments)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Expressions.JintCallExpression.EvaluateInternal(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Expressions.JintExpression.GetValue(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Statements.JintVariableDeclaration.ExecuteInternal(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.Native.Function.ScriptFunction.Call(JsValue thisObject, JsValue[] arguments)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Expressions.JintCallExpression.EvaluateInternal(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Expressions.JintExpression.GetValue(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Expressions.JintAssignmentExpression.SimpleAssignmentExpression.AssignToIdentifier(EvaluationContext context, JintIdentifierExpression left, JintExpression right, Boolean hasEvalOrArguments)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Statements.JintVariableDeclaration.ExecuteInternal(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.Native.Function.ScriptFunction.Call(JsValue thisObject, JsValue[] arguments)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Expressions.JintCallExpression.EvaluateInternal(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Expressions.JintExpression.GetValue(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.Runtime.Interpreter.Statements.JintExpressionStatement.ExecuteInternal(EvaluationContext context)
at Jint.Engine.ScriptEvaluation(ScriptRecord scriptRecord)
at Jint.Engine.ExecuteWithConstraints[T](Boolean strict, Func1 callback) at Jint.Engine.Execute(Script script) at Jint.Engine.Evaluate(String code) at Lending.FrozenFlow.Core.DSL.Misc.ScriptFlow.ExecuteScriptOptimisticallyAndGetNextPage(ExecutionContext1 result, String script) in C:\ML\as.accessdigital.lending.shared.babbler.nodes\AS.Lending.FrozenFlow.Core\DSL\Misc\ScriptFlow.cs:line 173
at Lending.FrozenFlow.Core.DSL.Misc.ScriptFlow.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.b__0(ExecutionContext`1 result) in C:\ML\as.accessdigital.lending.shared.babbler.nodes\AS.Lending.FrozenFlow.Core\DSL\Misc\ScriptFlow.cs:line 201

Welcome. Can you please show the full error message?

Sure, attached to the description of issue. Thank you
